# Can't connect to the containers using OpenVPN and Proxmox VE

Tags: networking, openvpn

I got a system set up constructed of Proxmox VE containers. Every container got access to the internet using iptabels POSTROUTING. They can ping themselves and the others and the hostnode. Everything works so far. Now this is where it get's tricky: I want to use OpenVPN to connect the proxmox server to another network. Everything works so far and I can ping the proxmox node. But I can't ping the containers, simulated by proxmox.

Let's say:

Proxmox (IP: 192.168.100.1)

Container1 (IP: 10.0.2.101)

Container2 (IP: 10.0.2.102)

Client in other network (IP: 192.168.1.42)

Container 1 (C1) and Container 2 (C2) pinging each other works. C1 and C2 pinging Proxmox works. Client in other network pinging Proxmox works. Client in other netzwork pinging C1 or C2 doesn't work and pinging the client in other network to C1 and C2 doesn't work. The containers use venet0:0.

Is this even possible? If so, how?